# Symfony: Authentication request failed: Invalid CSRF token

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I am getting the following error on logging in to a Symfony2 application:

> [2014-06-27 00:36:22] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Invalid CSRF token. [] []

Running on:

- Symfony2
- SonataUserBundle
- Vagrant (using puppet via Puphpet.com)
- Safari/OSX

Same setting is Working on an Ubuntu host system.

Thanks for any help.

security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
        logout:
            invalidate_session : false
            path: fos_user_security_logout
        anonymous: true
        switch_user: true
```

Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {{ error|trans }}
    </div>
{% endif %}

<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label required" for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="Username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label required" for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Password" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-5">
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
                <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-5">
                <a href="{{ path("fos_user_resetting_request") }}">{{ 'resetting.request.submit'|trans }}</a>
                <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" class="btn btn-primary form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Anything else is used of the FOSUserBundle and SonataUserBundle

Comment: could you post some code ( your login file  )

Comment: Of course, see above.

Comment: did the input `_csrf_token` has a value when you get the login page ? ( you could inspect it with developper tools in the navigator )

Comment: Yes, input field is filled with token:

<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="0C9QydjbN8w1dyneXFeQXzZzxY6aESuKHD1PKlGLRZg" />

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could solve my problem now. It seems to be a problem with write permissions on the session save path. If I change the configuration to use the default session save path as following:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        save_path: null
```

Then `/var/lib/php/session` is used instead of `/var/www/myproject/app/cache/dev/sessions`

The permissions on `/var/www/crowdcustoms/app/cache/dev/sessions`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 501 dialout    136 Jun 29 20:37 sessions/
```

The permissions on `/var/lib/php/session`

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 29 20:36 session
```

Comment: Also

drwxrwxrwx   4 501 dialout    136 Jun 29 20:37 sessions/

does not work using Symfonys session save path.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the context, `csrf_token('authentication')` should do the trick!

Ref: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/csrf_in_login_form.html

Comment: Hi, the token value is available. I tried your fix but doesn't change anyway. Same software is also working on another host system.