# Thelia/Symfony login error: session misconfiguration causing "Invalid CSRF Token"

Tags: symfony, session

I installed [Thelia](http://thelia.net) manually (via compressed archive) and set up my local server in a Vagrant box. Now when I go to login as the admin user I created during installation, I get:

> Please check your input: Missing or invalid data: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

I traced the issue to the `Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStorage` class: `$storage->hasToken()` was returning `false`. I then discovered that no `$_SESSION` variables I was setting manually were persisting at all. For example, I inserted each of the following lines in the code before two consecutive form posts, respectively:

```
die($_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar'); // output 'bar'
die($_SESSION['foo']); // Notice: Undefined index: foo
```

Also, if I add `die($data['$this->fieldName']);` inside `CsrfValidationListener` right before the Exception producing the error message is thrown, I get what sure as heck looks like a security token printed to the screen. So I'm pretty sure the token is getting created; it's just not getting making it into the session.

I know sessions are working properly for other sites I'm running inside this same Vagrant box. So what I'm wondering is if Thelia is configuring a session handler behind the scenes that is trying to write to a file it doesn't have write permissions on, or something along those lines? To that end, I tried doing `chmod 777 project/path/local/session` but that didn't appear to have any effect.

I also tried the solution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441412/symfony-authentication-request-failed-invalid-csrf-token) by creating a local/config/config.yml file:

```
# local/config/config.yml
framework:
  session:
    save_path: /var/lib/php5/sessions/ # <- gleaned from phpinfo()
```

Same error.

Does Thelia use file-based session handling by default? If so, where does it keep them, if not in local/session/? If not, what do I need to do to get sessions working? **(See below for revised question)**

**UPDATE:** I installed Thelia fresh on a different Vagrant box, and began getting these errors in the Apache logs:

```
PHP Warning:  SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid in /vagrant/projects/thelia/core/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php on line 69
PHP Warning:  SessionHandler::write(): Session data file is not created by your uid in /vagrant/projects/thelia/core/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php on line 77
```

Running `strace` confirmed that it was trying to open the file under local/session:

```
open("/vagrant/projects/thelia//local/session//sess_u32o90k65sesi763rddb9lk1s2", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_NOFOLLOW, 0600) = 21
```

The only way I could get the session data to persist was to hard-code an override into `Thelia\Model\ConfigQuery`, which is responsible for telling Thelia where to read/write session data:

```
class ConfigQuery extends BaseConfigQuery
{

    public static function read($search, $default = null)
    {
        if($search === 'session_config.save_path') return '/var/lib/php5/sessions/';
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So my question is now this: **Where can I actually configure Thelia to do this so I don't have to hack the bundle code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this row to the `config` table:

```
INSERT INTO `config` (`name`, `value`, `secured`, `hidden`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('session_config.save_path', '/var/lib/php5/sessions/', 0, 0, NOW(), NOW())
```

Comment: AHA! I didn't realize Thelia read that configuration from the database. Would've expected something like that to be documented on the [Configuration](http://doc.thelia.net/en/documentation/configuration/config_vars.html) page or somewhere similar...

Comment: I'd expect that as well, but then a quick search on the github repository was faster : https://github.com/thelia/thelia/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=session_config